# Node.js app receives empty response from GET request to API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm new to node.js so I'll try my best to explain the problem here. Let me know if any clerification is needed.

In my node.js application I'm trying to take a code (which was received from the response of the 1st call to an API), and use that a code to make a 2nd request(GET request) to another API service. The callback url of the 1st call is `/pass`. However I got an `empty response` from the service for this 2nd call.

My understanding is that after the call back from the 1st call, the function in `app.get('/pass', function (req, res)..` gets invoked and it sends a `GET` request. What am I doing wrong here? Many thanks in advance!

Here is the part where I try to make a GET request from node.js server and receive an empty response:

```
    app.get('/pass', function (req, res){

    var options = {  
        url: 'https://the url that I make GET request to',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'authorization_code': code,
            'Customer-Id':'someID',
            'Customer-Secret':'somePassword'
        }
    };

    request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there anything in `err`?

Comment: it says : `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 2):

Im a little confused by what you are asking so ill just try to cover what i think you're looking for.

```
app.get('/pass', (req, res) => {
    res.send("hello!");      // localhost:port/pass will return hello 
})
```

Now, if you are trying to call a get request from the request library when the /pass endpoint is called things are still similar. First, i think you can remove the 'method' : 'GET'  keys and values as they are not necessary. Now the code will be mostly the same as before except for the response.

```
app.get('/pass', (req, res) => {
    var options = {  
        url: 'https://the url that I make GET request to',
        headers: {
            'authorization_code': code,
            'Customer-Id':'someID',
            'Customer-Secret':'somePassword'
        }
    };

    request(options, function(err, res, body) {  
    // may need to JSONparse the body before sending depending on what is to be expected.
        res.send(body); // this sends the data back 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @reedb89 About `app.get('/pass', (req, res) `, it's the call back url from my previous call. I think after my node app receives the response from the 1st call, my browser goes to  localhost:8080/pass?code=xyz.... and I tried to use that code to make a 2nd call in this `app.get('/pass', (req,res)`. So I think the `res.send(body)` in your answer is the res from   the 2nd call? I don't understand why I need to send the data back?

Comment: what i want to do with the res from the 2nd call is that, I want to have a look at it first and retrieve some value from it.. That's why I tried to log it on to the console..

Comment: does console.log(body) give you what you are looking for?

Comment: No the `body` says 'undefined', same as `res`. The error I saw from the browser is first 'empty response' and then 'time out'. The `err, res, body` are the response I got from the request I sent to  `https://the url that I make GET request to` qith all the headers right?

Comment: The browser is displaying 'time out' because you are not returning a response. Yes, the err, res, body are from the options passed into the request method. Tbh I don't really see anything wrong here. Maybe try removing the headers and using www.google.com as a test. Is code a global var declared elsewhere? The documentation is very well defined in regards to headers: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: Thanks for suggesting using google as a test. I tried with google and it didn't work either! `app.get('/pass', function (req, res){
 console.log("in pass function");
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
});` In the browser log it says 'Provisional headers are shown
', and the request url is from localhost:8080/pass?code=... Could that bcs of something else? btw I declared code and was able to print it out